# Generate Random IP Address

Tags: java, ip, subnet

I want to generate some random IP Address. But evertime this generateIPAddress function returns 0.0.0.0 string as ipAddress. But it should be returning some random ipAddress other than 0.0.0.0 everytime. Any suggestions why is it happening?

```
private void callingGeoService() {
    int p1 = 255;
    int p2 = 0;
    int p3 = 0;
    int inc = 5;

    String ipAddress = generateIPAddress(p1, p2, p3);

    p3 += inc;
    if (p3 > 255) {
        p3 = 0;
        p2 += inc;
        if (p2 > 255) {
            p2 = 0;
            p1--;
            if (p1 <= 0) {
                p1 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the generateIPAddress method

```
private String generateIPAddress(int p1, int p2, int p3) {

    StringBuilder sb = null;

    int b1 = (p1 >> 24) & 0xff;
    int b2 = (p2 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int b3 = (p3 >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b4 = 0;

    String ip1 = Integer.toString(b1);
    String ip2 = Integer.toString(b2);
    String ip3 = Integer.toString(b3);
    String ip4 = Integer.toString(b4);

    //Now the IP is b1.b2.b3.b4
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(ip1).append(".").append(ip2).append(".").append(ip3).append(".").append(ip4);
    // System.out.println(sb);

    return sb.toString();

}
```

I want a random value assigned to `ipAddress` in the form of `p1,p2,p3` and last bit should be `0`.

Comment: Java does not have such a thing as out-parameters

Comment: What does that mean. I was not able to understand?

Comment: Oh never mind; I thought you wanted to assign something to p1/p2/p3, but I was a bit too quick responding. Still not sure what the modification (`p3 += inc;` etc.) should do after calling `generateIPAddress`. I should have said: Java does not have method  level static variables, since the modification of p1/p2/p3 will be lost after leaving the method scope.

Comment: http://www.texamples.com/how-to-generate-random-passwords-in-java/ this might help you.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
return r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256);
```

Comment: This generates a whole bunch of questionable addresses; things like 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255, as well as private IP address ranges and multicast addresses.

Comment: 255.255.255.255 is the universal broadcast address. use this one with cautions !

Answer (score 14):

Using [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
import com.google.common.net.InetAddresses;
...
String ipString = InetAddresses.fromInteger(random.nextInt()).getHostAddress();
```

of course you can validate the resulting address not to be multicast etc.

Comment: This answer has the same defects as the accepted answer and could generate IP addresses like `0.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.255`.

Comment: Does this library support generating a random IPv6 IP based on a given subnet?

Answer (score 4):

I've recently developed a [small library](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat) that can generate random IPv4 addresses using different type constraints:

```
MockNeat mock = MockNeat.threadLocal();

String ipv4 = mock.ipv4s().val();
System.out.println(ipv4);

String ipClassA = mock.ipv4s().type(CLASS_A).val();
System.out.println(ipClassA);

String classAorB = mock.ipv4s().types(CLASS_A, CLASS_B).val();
System.out.println(classAorB);

List<String> ip4s = mock.ipv4s().list(10).val();
System.out.println(ip4s);
```

Output:

```
192.112.222.183
120.178.110.193
143.68.176.47
[112.246.76.178, 29.201.72.151, 67.105.2.128, 102.189.109.206, 157.146.176.212, 59.220.145.35, 47.171.185.233, 162.245.163.124, 19.203.21.194, 114.177.238.50]
```

Comment: I've tried it and it's good! Does CLASS_A exclude CLASS_A_PRIVATE?

Comment: No it doesn't. It's included.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So I don't seem to be able to make sure to get an address that is not private

Comment: Yes. Good observation. Can you add this as an issue on the project's github. I will implement it is in the future release.

Comment: Classful networks have been deprectaed in **1993**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't actually care about the resultant IP address being valid in any form whatsoever, you have a simple problem.

The code for generating the addresses sets the parameters `p3` and `p2` to something less than `255`. `p1` is trapped between `255` and `0`.

The real problem is that the code that turns this into an address shifts these values. `p1` by `24`, `p2` by `16` and `p3` by `8`. Understanding the limitation applied in the calling method, you can know that `p1`, `p2` and `p3` will never exceed `255`, so in this case knowing that a shift of `8` or more will result in `0`, none of the individual elements of the address will result in a value other than `0`, and the last octet will always be `0`, so the resultant address will be `0.0.0.0`

If you want to prevent it from being `0.0.0.0`, the first thing to do is remove the shift operations. This will still keep the last field as `0`, because it is never set, but it should produce addresses.

Again, this is not caring about the state of the addresses, you will end up with broadcast, multicast and local-only addresses using this method.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `generateIPAddress(p1, p2, p3)`, `p1` is `255`, `p2` and `p3` are `0`.

This line

```
int b1 = (p1 >> 24) & 0xff;
```

shifts `p1` 24 bits to the right. Before the shift `p1` was `11111111`. The shift results with `0`. Actually you could also use

```
int b1 = p1 >> 8;
```

as `p1` has only its 8 least significant bits turned on. The use of `& 0xff` is redundant as the operation is between two `int` operands. So `b1` is `0`.

`p2` and `p3` are passed with the value `0` so the shift (either by `16` or `8`) doesn't change it one bit, resulting with `b2` and `b3` being also `0`.

`b4` is explicitly set to `0`.

So all `b1`, `b2`, `b3` and `b4` are `0`, from which you create `ip1` to `ip4`. So the method `generateIPAddress(p1, p2, p3)` always returns `0.0.0.0`.

Then `p3 += inc;` adds `5` to `0`. Reuslt in `p3` now is `5`.

The condition `if (p3 > 255)` will always fail as `p3` is `5` which is `< 255`...

Answer (score 0):

**To generate random IP address with [Subnet Mask](https://www.iplocation.net/subnet-mask) use the below code** (Note that in this code Subnet Mask has [CIDR](https://www.oav.net/mirrors/cidr.html) format):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClas {

    public static int findRange(int mask)
    {
        int x = 8 - mask;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++) {
            sum += Math.pow(2 , i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int findFixedPart(String IPPrefix, int i)
    {
        String f = IPPrefix.split("\\.")[i];
        return Integer.valueOf(f);
    }

    public static String generateRandomIP(String IPPrefix, Integer mask)
    {
        String IP="";
        Random r = new Random();
        if (mask < 8)
            IP = (findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 0) + r.nextInt(findRange(mask))) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256);
        else if (mask >7 && mask < 16)
            IP = findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 0) + "." + (findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 1) + r.nextInt(findRange(mask-8))) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256);
        else if (mask >15 && mask < 24)
            IP = findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 0) + "." + findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 1)  + "." + (findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 2) + r.nextInt(findRange(mask-16))) + "." + r.nextInt(256);
        else if (mask >23 && mask < 33)
            IP = findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 0) + "." + findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 1)  + "." + findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 2) + "." + (findFixedPart(IPPrefix, 3) + r.nextInt(findRange(mask-24)));
        return IP;
    }

    public static void main(String[] inpout)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter IP Prefix: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String IPPrefix = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Mask: ");
        Integer mask = sc.nextInt();

        // Find random IP in Subnet mask
        String IP = generateRandomIP(IPPrefix, mask);
        System.out.println(IP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this function will help you to generate an infinite number of a random IP address:

```
        StringBuilder ip = new StringBuilder("xx.xx.xx.xx");
            for (int i=0 ; i <11;i++){

                if (i==2){}
                else if (i==5){}
                else if (i==8){}
                else{
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int random = r.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                    char c = (char)(random+'0');
                    ip.setCharAt(i, c);
                }

            }

            Log.v("ip","Server IP : "+ip);
```

As you see i generate xx.xx.xx.xx ip format and you can handle it to generate any ip format.

Comment: An IPv4 address is not "xx.xx.xx.xx", it is 4 8-bit integers, or one 32-bits integer if you prefer. By just avoiding the first digit in a 10-based output, you just restrict the outgoing space of possible values, for no reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short code to filter out ranges listed in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addressing) as special (slightly more as only based on 1st octet):

```
Random r = new Random();
Integer prefix;
while ({
    prefix = r.nextInt(256);
    prefix in [0,10,100,127,172,192,198,203,224,240,255]
}());   
return prefix + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and fast way to generate a random ip address:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class IpAddressHelper {

     public static String createRandom() {
         return randomNumber() + "." + randomNumber() + "." + randomNumber() + "." + randomNumber();
     }

     public static int randomNumber() {
         return new Random().nextInt((255 - 1) + 1) + 1;
     }
}
```