# Random unique number like IP address mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm making an android game which is made with a hacking theme, and I want to generate a random and unique IP address-style user ID (example xxx.xxx.xx.xx)

At the moment I know how to generate a unique ID, but it is just incremented from 1 and up.

I don't know if it is maybe only possible through php?
Or even the android app's side?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this on Android app side,

```
Random random = new Random();
return random.nextInt(256) + "." + random.nextInt(256) + "." + random.nextInt(256) + "." + random.nextInt(256);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236197/generate-random-ip-address) SO thread.

Edit : To generate random numbers without repeatations, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates) thread. You will have to modify it for your need though.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to make it unique, because I think this might generate two of the same numbers (the chances are **VERY** slim but still possible). Any idea on that?

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get back on my PC! Thanks so far!